# Python 3.6 Object/Class Threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm looking to create a "self contained threaded class" using Python 3.

At a high level, want I would liked to do is to spawn up 50 asynchronous device objects from my "main" class and then just use their methods as needed. This is not difficult when just dealing with objects in synchronous situation but gets cloudy quite quickly as we move to asynchronous processing.  The primary idea to keep the threading self contained in the device class so my base (main.py) code stays streamlined/clean and without any of the thread management.

I don't plan on any resource sharing in this case so I think I'm clear of any thread lock issues.

Here is some sample code that I hope someone can provide some hints or samples into making it a self threaded class (meaning I don't want to manage threads at the main.py level):

## Sample main.py

```
from deviceworker import Device

availableworkers = {'USA':'services.groupkt.com', 'IND':'services.groupkt.com'}
Activeworkers = []

for name, ip in availableworkers.items():
    Activeworkers.append(Device(name, ip))

for worker in Activeworkers:
    worker.checkcountry()   # asynchronous call - (we don't want to wait for a response)
                            # The idea is to keep this code as clean as possible.
```

## Sample Object: deviceworker.py

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json

class Device:
    def __init__(self, name, endpoint, preamble = 'state', port = 80 ):

        self.name = name
        self.connected =False
        self.connection = HTTPConnection(endpoint, preamble, port)
        self.getStatus()

    def getStatus(self, check_for = None):
        self.urlresponse = json.loads(self.connection.GET('get/USA/all')) #Use USA just to verify connection
        if check_for:
            pass

        self.connected = True

    def checkcountry(self):
        print(self.connection.GET('get/%s/all' % self.name))

class HTTPConnection:
    def __init__(self, endpoint, preamble = None, port = 80):

        if preamble: # specificing a version after the port and before method
            self.url = 'http://%s:%s/%s/' % (endpoint, port, preamble)
        else:
            self.url = 'http://%s:%s/' % (endpoint, port)
        print('_init_ url=%s' % self.url)

    def GET(self, operation):
        #try:
            #print('%s%s' % (self.url, operation))
        with urllib.request.urlopen('%s%s' % (self.url, operation)) as f:
             return f.read().decode('utf-8')
        #except Exception as e:
            #raise Exception("GET Request Failed")
```

I've stripped most of the exception handling for simplicity.  The sample above should work.

## --- UPDATE ---

So I think I've sort of figured it out.  Still not getting the parrellism I would expect from the documentation.

```
import threading
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json
import time


class Device(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, endpoint, preamble = 'state', port = 80 ):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.connected = False
        self.connection = HTTPConnection(endpoint, preamble, port)
        print('%s: __init__' % self.name)

    def run(self):
        self.getStatus()
        print('%s: hit run()' % self.name)

    def getStatus(self):
        self.urlresponse = json.loads(self.connection.GET('get/USA/all')) #Use USA just to verify connection
        self.connected = True

    def checkcountry(self):
        if (self.name == 'USA'): self.waittime = 10
        else: self.waittime = 0

        print('%s: Getting Codes - wait time: %s' % (self.name, self.waittime))

        start_time=time.time()
        time.sleep(self.waittime)
        result =self.connection.GET('get/%s/all' % self.name)
        elapsed_time=time.time() - start_time
        print('%s: Got Codes - second: %s' % (self.name, elapsed_time))


class HTTPConnection:
    def __init__(self, endpoint, preamble = None, port = 80):
        if preamble: # specificing a version after the port and before method
            self.url = 'http://%s:%s/%s/' % (endpoint, port, preamble)
        else:
            self.url = 'http://%s:%s/' % (endpoint, port)

    def GET(self, operation):
        with urllib.request.urlopen('%s%s' % (self.url, operation)) as f:
             return f.read().decode('utf-8')


DeviceList = {'USA':'services.groupkt.com', 'IND':'services.groupkt.com'}
ActiveDevices = []

DeviceList = {'USA':'services.groupkt.com', 'IND':'services.groupkt.com'}
ActiveDevices = []

for name, ip in DeviceList.items():
    print('main: creating object for: %s' % name)
    newDevice = Device(name, ip)
    ActiveDevices.append(newDevice)
    newDevice.start()

for device in ActiveDevices:
    print('main: calling checkcountry() for: %s' % device.name)
    device.checkcountry()
```

Here are the results:

```
main: creating object for: USA
USA: __init__
main: creating object for: IND
IND: __init__
main: calling checkcountry() for: USA
USA: Getting Codes - wait time: 10
USA: Got Codes - second: 10.167016744613647
main: calling checkcountry() for: IND
IND: Getting Codes - wait time: 0
IND: Got Codes - second: 0.11001110076904297
```

I by adding in the delay to the USA search I would have expected the IND to finish first but it appears that it serialized.

I'm running this on:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

Comment: This is easy in your example... you could just do `threading.Thread(target=worker.checkcountry)` and you could even write a decorator on `def checkcountry`. The script would wait for the threads to complete when it exits. It gets more complicated for a longer running script that wants to call things arbitrarily because of the potential for background tasks to grow to the point where the program crashes. So... is this the second case? Is this a long-running program that will multiple times?

Comment: Yes - but not extremely long running.  In this example, managing devices using a REST interface, it would be making a series of API calls, checking the results, and then shutting down.  So long running up to an hour I would suppose.

Comment: The threading.thread suggestion doesn't keep the main.py clean which is why I am looking for a more of a "self contained" thread management implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom thread sample with locking worked great for me, better than using the event.

Try it in Colab.

```
import threading,time

i=0

luk=threading.Lock()


global i
global y
global t_num

class special_thread(threading.Thread):
    """This function starts a Thread class"""
    def __init__(self, execute,threadID , name,  daemon,args=(), repetitive=False,kwargs=None, interval_sec=60 ):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = daemon
        self.stopped = threading.Event()
        self.interval_sec = interval_sec
        self.execute = execute
        self.name = name
        if kwargs is None:
            kwargs = {}
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs=kwargs
        self.repetitive=repetitive
        self.threadID = threadID
        print(args)
    def stop(self):
        self.stopped.set()
        self.join()

    def run(self):
        if self.repetitive:
            while not self.stopped.wait(self.interval_sec):
                self.execute(*self.args,**self.kwargs)
        else:
            self.execute(*self.args,**self.kwargs)


def center(t_num):
    y=0
    
    luk.acquire()
    caller = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1][3]
    print(' {} is aquiring by {} '.format( caller,  str(time.ctime())))
    y+=t_num
    
    print( "Inside %s()" % caller)
    print('thread number is ',t_num,y)
    time.sleep(2*t_num)
    luk.release()
    print(' {} is releasing  by {} '.format( caller,  str(time.ctime())))

def target_uno():
  t_num=1
  center(t_num)

def target_dos():
  t_num=2
  center(t_num)


target_uno=special_thread(execute=target_uno, args=(),repetitive=True, interval_sec=1,threadID=10004,
                                                  name='target_uno',
                                                  daemon=False )

target_dos=special_thread(execute=target_dos, args=(),repetitive=True, interval_sec=1,threadID=10004,
                                                  name='target_dos',
                                                  daemon=False )

if __name__ == "__main__":

  target_uno.start()
  target_dos.start()
  time.sleep(20)
  target_uno.stop()
  target_dos.stop()
```